# How to set fields inline in views in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, view, field

I am working on a website using drupal. I have created a view with several fields.  I want to set some  if the field inline horizontally not not one after another vertically. Please help me in the context.
I want to set these ratings start , I'm interested button and Read More link  in a row.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with html and css, you can create a new "Global: Custom Text" field.

Exclude the other fields from display, and use Replacement Patterns inside styled div-containers specified in the custom text field.

Little dirty example working with float:

```
<div style="width:50%;height:200px;float:left;">
  <div style="width:100%;">Next div below me</div>
  <div style="width:100%;">Previous div above me [somereplacementpattern]</div>
</div>
<div style="width:50%;height:200px;float:left;">
  <div style="width:auto;float:left;">Next div on my right</div>
  <div style="width:auto;float:left;">Previous div on my left<div>
</div>
```